# Error with injection of restangular

Tags: angularjs, syntax, restangular

I have an error injection when i put this code :

```
    /* start */
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'Restangular', 'ngStorage']);

   /* first controller */
    app.controller('RSSFBCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {

    /*(here my code for get a facebook json)*/

    });
```

error :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error…arjs.org%2F1.3.0-beta.7%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DRestangular%26p1%3...<omitted>...6)
```

what's wrong ? syntax error ? :/ restangular is correctly added with script tag

Comment: Try lower case "restangular" in the module declaration (keep upper case in the controller). Sample code here... https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#quick-configuration-for-lazy-readers

Comment: not working, same error.

Comment: You've probably already checked this, but just to be sure, have you included the rectangular script before the instantiation of your AngularJS app so written above?

Comment: Ok good.  Any chance you could share a plunk or jsfiddle that has all/most of what you have so far (particularly the JS and HTML)?

Answer (score 1):

Try lower case "restangular" in the module declaration (keep upper case in the controller). Sample code here... https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#quick-configuration-for-lazy-readers